# Image path locations are not found?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Image is not shown.if there are placeholder cdn image which is shown but this image is not showing in the slider. so how can I import image from local images folder. image path is not found.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './hotels.css';
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';
import star from '../../../assets/images/star.png';
import loc from '../../../assets/images/loc.png';

export default class Hotels extends Component {

    render() {
        const images = [
            {
                original: '/src/assets/images/hotel1.png',
                thumbnail: '/src/assets/images/hotel1.png',
            },
            {
                original: '/src/assets/images/hotel1.png',
                thumbnail: '/src/assets/images/hotel1.png'
            },
            {
                original: '/src/assets/images/hotel1.png',
                thumbnail: '/src/assets/images/hotel1.png'
            }
        ]
        return (
            <div className="Hotels">
                <main className="main-wrap bg-white">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-7">
                            <ImageGallery items={images} thumbnailPosition='bottom' showGalleryPlayButton={false} showPlayButton={false} showFullscreenButton={false} showGalleryFullscreenButton={false} />

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </main>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you use those images in your `ImageGallery` component? Please share that component.

Comment: this is a slider http://linxtion.com/demo/react-image-gallery

Comment: So, you can't have control over how this component use the images?

Comment: @MD.ALIMULAlrazy I think the path has to be relative.  Like so `original: '../../../assets/images/hotel1.png'`

Comment: {
                original: 'https://placeimg.com/350/350/tech',
                thumbnail: 'https://placeimg.com/350/350/tech'
            }
if i put cdn link images are shown but in local storage it could not come

Answer (score 0):

Blind answer: Change `images` array like this:

```
const images = [
  {
    original: require("./assets/images/hotel1.png"),
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/hotel1.png")
  },
  {
    original: require("./assets/images/hotel1.png"),
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/hotel1.png")
  },
  {
    original: require("./assets/images/hotel1.png"),
    thumbnail: require("./assets/images/hotel1.png")
  }
];
```

You should `require` images and it uses a relative path string. Also, you can't use `/src/..` You should use a relative path.

As a side note, try to define images outside of the render. As in this situation, they will be redefined in every render.

Comment: const images = [
            {
                original: require("../../../assets/images/hotel1.png"),
                thumbnail: require("../../../assets/images/hotel1.png")
                
              },
              {
                original: require("../../../assets/images/hotel1.png"),
                thumbnail: require("../../../assets/images/hotel1.png")
                
              }
        ]
this path is working but thanks man.

Comment: No problem, I thought you are using CRA.